# ArangoDB: Split collection that does not fit into memory

Tags: arangodb

I have painted myself into a corner by creating a collection in ArangoDB that is too large to fit into memory. When I try to load it, my computer reports RAM and hard disk usage of 100% ... I waited for twenty minutes, but the collection was not loaded.

Is there a way to split the collection into smaller parts without loading it? Maybe via the Arango Shell, or by playing around with the database files? (I am using Windows 8.1).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it is possible to split the collection without loading but using ArangoDB with the storage engine "rocksdb" could solve your problem, whereas "mmfiles" is the default storage engine.

Rocksdb is optimized for datasets that are bigger than main memory. The engine stores a hot set of data in main memory and is still able to load additional data from disk if it is not cached in the hot set.

Comment: Can I reinstall ArangoDB with the 'rocksdb' and still use the database I have created with the 'mmfiles' engine?

Comment: Yes this is possible. You can export your database with arangodump and import it with arangorestore.

Comment: Documented here: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/Administration/Upgrading/Upgrading32.html